# How Electromotive force works in Electric Generator?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Electromotive Force is often mentioned in Battery (I don't know how it works in battery), but I want to know how it works in [electric generator](http://www.smartlearner.mobi/science/VideoPastPapers/Electrodynamics/Images/Electrodynamics_papers_70.jpg)....

I can't find any explanation that that makes me clearly understand it.

[How magnetic Induction Works?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282922/how-magnetic-induction-works) <-- *"When the magnetic flux through the wire changes, as it moves down, Faraday's law of induction says that it acquires an **electromotive force**."*

*"The "**electromotive force**" will now cause a current to flow in the external resistor R. This means that a similar current (electron flow) flows through the rod PQ itself, giving a magnetic force to the left."*

So *electromotive force* is the main thing that makes electrons move (electric current) in one direction?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find any explanation that that makes me clearly understand it.

An electromotive force means a voltage across two points which can do work, like the electrical outlet in your home, or a battery.

> So electromotive force is the main thing that makes electrons move (electric current) in one direction?

Yes, a voltage between two points makes current flow in a conductor connected to the two points.